# C Print element of Array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

Okay, so I have an array that I get from the user, then I switch the array to show the numbers in descending order (bubble sort).

Now I need to print out the first element (first index) of the new array and the second index of the new array. Then sum of the two biggest array numbers.
But I don't know why it won't show the number. Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int array[100], n, c, d, swap, sum;

        printf("Enter number of horses\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);

        printf("Enter %d horse powers\n", n);

        for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
            scanf_s("%d", &array[c]);


        //This switches the array to show descending order numbers
        for (c = 0; c < (n - 1); c++)
        {
            for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
            {
                if (array[d] < array[d + 1]) 
                {
                    swap = array[d];
                    array[d] = array[d + 1];
                    array[d + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

        printf("This is the new array descending:\n");
        for (c = 0; c < n; c++){
            printf("%d\n", array[c]);
        }
        //Help here 
        printf("Biggest number" + array[0]);
        printf("Second biggest number" + array[1]);

        sum = array[0] + array[1];
        printf("Sum of two biggest numbers is: " + sum);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not told most of the printfs to expect an argument.
e.g.

`printf("Sum of two biggest numbers is: " + sum);`

should be

`printf("Sum of two biggest numbers is: %d\n", sum);`

Comment: Okay I changed that but I still get an error. I believe I am missing something when printing the Biggest number and Second biggest number.

Comment: Not an error. It prints out this after the new array:
 numberd biggest numberiggest numbers is: Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Your going to have to do some debugging. Hard for anyone else to help without knowing value of `n` etc.

Comment: @RadLexus Good point - fixed the first glaring issue and missed the second one. Fixed now though.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` takes arguments.

What you should have written is

`printf("Biggest number %d\n", array[0]);`

`printf("Second biggest number %d\n", array[1]);`

`printf("Sum of two biggest numbers is: %d\n", sum);`

Comment: This is what I get, after the new array:
est number 15405321
ond biggest number 15405321
two biggest numbers is: 15405321
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @ivan How does that help anyone to help you? We don't know what numbers you entered, so we don't know if that is expected of not...

Comment: @Ivan  It seems you did not update all the statements with printf as it is suggested in this post.:)